# How render a view template from another controller and pass is a local variable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

In Ruby on Rails, how can I render a partial from another controller's namespace and pass an object as a local variable?

For example, in a view template in the `views/posts` directory (managed by the `PostsController`), I need render a partial from the `views/polls` directory.

I've tried the following:

```
.item_index  
  = f.fields_for :poll_items do |poll|
    = render :partial => 'polls/poll_item_fields', f: poll
  .links
    = link_to_add_association 'Add more', f, :poll_items, render_options: {class: 'links'}
```

and I've got error:

```
Showing /home/ubuntu/workspace/app/views/polls/_poll_item_fields.html.haml where line #3 raised:
undefined local variable or method `f' for #<#<Class:0x0000000c01ec38>:0x0000000f56b170>**
```

**EDIT**

All complete views:

**posts/new.html.haml**

```
%h1= title "New post"
= simple_form_for [@group, @post] do |f|
  = f.error_messages header_message: nil
  = render 'form', f: f

  .form-actions
    %p= attach_links
    = f.button :submit, 'Опубликовать пост', class: 'btn-bg'
    - if paid?
      = f.button :submit, 'сохранить черновик', class: 'btn-inverse', name: 'draft'
    = button_tag 'Добавить опрос', type: 'button', id: 'poll-btn', class: 'btn btn-bg'
    %p
      Вернуться в группу:
      = link_to @group, @group
```

**posts/_form.html.haml**

```
- cat = Post::CATEGORIES.map { |c| [t(c, scope: :post_categories), c] }
= f.input :category, collection: cat
= f.input :subject, input_html: { class: 'input-block-level' }
= f.input :body, input_html: { rows: 5, class: 'ctrlenter input-block-level expanding' }
= link_to "#", class: 'smiley', role: 'add_smiley', tabidex: 4 do
  %i.icon.icon-smile
  смайлы
= smiles_helper '#post_body'

.form-horizontal
  = f.input :tag_list, input_html: { class: 'input-block-level' }
  - if (current_user.paid? && current_user.moderated_group_ids.include?(@group.id)) || moderator?
    = f.input :comments_disabled, inline_label: true, label: false
.attachments
  = f.simple_fields_for :attachments do |af|
    = render "attachments/#{af.object.asset_type.underscore}", :f => af
.poll{style: "display: none;"}
  %h1 "Новый опрос"
  = f.simple_fields_for :poll do |poll|
    = render "polls/poll_fields", f: poll
```

**polls/_poll_fields.html.haml**

```
= f.error_messages header_message: nil
= f.input :question, input_html: { class: 'input-block-level' }
= f.input :results_hidden, as: :boolean, inline_label: 'Скрыть результаты до окончания опроса', label: false
= f.input :from_date, as: :datetime, input_html: { class: 'poll_date' }
= f.input :to_date, as: :datetime, input_html: { class: 'poll_date' }
%h3#poll-items Варианты ответа (не больше пяти)
.item_index  
  = f.fields_for :poll_items do |poll_item|
    = render partial: 'polls/poll_item_fields', locals: {f: poll_item}
  .links
    = link_to_add_association 'Добавить еще вариант', f, :poll_items, render_options: {class: 'links'}
```

**polls/poll_items_fields**

```
.poll_row
  .poll_item
    = f.input :answer, input_html: { class: 'ctrlenter expanding' }, label: false, placeholder: 'Введите вариант ответа'
    = link_to_remove_association "удалить", f, { wrapper_class: 'poll_item' }
```

When use `= render partial: 'polls/poll_item_fields', locals: { f: poll }`, display error: **howing /home/ubuntu/workspace/app/views/polls/_poll_fields.html.haml where line #11 raised: howing /home/ubuntu/workspace/app/views/polls/_poll_fields.html.haml where line #11 raised: 
Missing partial posts/poll_item_fields**

Line 11 is `= link_to_add_association 'Add more', f, :poll_items, render_options: {class: 'links'}`

Answer (score 0):

When passing variables to a partial via `render`, you need to wrap them in a `locals` key:

```
= render partial: 'polls/poll_item_fields', locals: { f: poll }
```

For more detail, see the [Layouts and Rendering guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials).

Comment: i tryed. display error: **Missing partial posts/poll_item_fields**.

Comment: But it didn't complain about the missing partial without the `locals` key?

Comment: no ,it didn't complain about the missing partial without the locals key.

Comment: when use = render partial: 'polls/poll_item_fields', locals: { f: poll }, display error: **howing /home/ubuntu/workspace/app/views/polls/_poll_fields.html.haml where line #11 raised:

Missing partial posts/poll_item_fields**   11 line is **= link_to_add_association 'Add more', f, :poll_items, render_options: {class: 'links'}**

Answer (score 0):

There are two forms of the `render` method, which let you pass locals in different ways.

The *shortcut* version will accept a `Hash`:

```
= render 'polls/poll_item_fields', f: poll
```

You, however, are using the *long* version. If you use the `partial` key, then you also need to use the `locals` key:

```
= render partial: 'polls/poll_item_fields', locals: { f: poll }
```

That's not just a matter of style, but it's because of how ruby treats method arguments.

In the *shortcut* version, the first argument is a `String` and the second a `Hash`. Rails will know that the `Hash` will contain locals.
In the second version, however, the first (and only) argument is a `Hash`. Without the `:locals` key, and thanks to Ruby's syntax that allows to omit parenthesis and curly braces, it would be translated to this:

```
render({ partial: 'polls/poll_item_fields', f: poll })
```

Which will leave Rails a bit confused as it won't be able to isolate the locals from the other keyed options passed to the method.

In the end it's still a matter of style: the methods signatures have been designed like that. I hope that my explanation makes things a bit clearer!

Comment: Thank you for you unswer, but how me fix my error? Its issue becose conflict with other local key f?

Comment: when use = render partial: 'polls/poll_item_fields', locals: { f: poll }, display error: **howing /home/ubuntu/workspace/app/views/polls/_poll_fields.html.haml where line #11 raised: Missing partial posts/poll_item_fields** 11 line is **= link_to_add_association 'Add more', f, :poll_items, render_options: {class: 'links'}**